# Row/column names from a correlation matrix values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I calculated a correlation matrix in spark and I want to extract single correlations in combination with their column names.

**Correlation Matrix**

```
correlMatrix: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix = 
1.0                   -0.33333333333333254  -0.8164965809277261  -0.7777777777777787   
-0.33333333333333254  1.0                   0.8164965809277356   -0.33333333333333254  
-0.8164965809277261   0.8164965809277356    1.0                  0.27216552697591645   
-0.7777777777777787   -0.33333333333333254  0.27216552697591645  1.0
```

**Datafarme Names**

```
colNames: Array[String] = Array(item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4)
```

Now I want to extract each combination into dataframe with the following structure:

```
item_from | item_to | Correlation
item_1    | item_2  | -0.0096912
item_1    | item_3  | -0.7313071
item_2    | item_3  | 0.68910356
```

Or at least the whole correlation matrix with column names:

```
           item_1                item_2                item_3          item_4
item_1     1.0                   -0.33333333333333254  -0.8164965809277261  -0.7777777777777787   
item_2     -0.33333333333333254  1.0                   0.8164965809277356   -0.33333333333333254  
item_3     -0.8164965809277261   0.8164965809277356    1.0                  0.27216552697591645   
item_4     -0.7777777777777787   -0.33333333333333254  0.27216552697591645  1.0
```

I've tried to write a map function but it didn't work as I expected.

Is there any solution you could suggest?

Answer (score 2):

```
val colNamePairs = colsNames.flatMap(c1 => colsNames.map(c2 => (c1, c2)))

val triplesList = colNamePairs.zip(correlMatrix.toArray)
  .filterNot(p => p._1._1 >= p._1._2)
  .map(r => (r._1._1, r._1._2, r._2))

val corrDF = sc.parallelize(triplesList).toDF("item_from", "item_to", "Correlation")
```

*colNamePairs* produces all the combinations of column names
*triplesList* represents the list of triples composed by (colName1, colName2, correlation)

Finally, we convert it to a DF with the sought column names.

Please note the filterNot is optional, there only to keep half of the matrix (excluding the diagonal) as it is symmetric and thus redundant, if you want the full list just remove it.